# Changes values based on key in php array

Tags: php, arrays

Set keys based on array values.

```
$ids= array(1,2,3,5,7,8);

$newkeys = array('hck','scr','lcss','ftbl','bsktbl','stbl');
$array = array_combine(array_map(function($el) use ($newkeys) {
  return $newkeys[$el];
}, array_keys($ids )), array_values($ids ));

//Show Value    
print_r($array);
die;
```

What i want check my array ids if value it has value 1 than set key as hck and its associated value will be 1, if ids has 2 value then set key as scr and its value will be scr....so on...

if we have `ids = array(1,3,7,8)` then the output will be as below

```
Array
(
    [hck] => 1
    [lcss] => 3
    [bsktbl] => 7
    [stbl] => 8
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this you just need to create an array for your key value refrence then you can easily map values from that array to any given input array of ids

```
    $ids= array(1,2,3,5,7,8);
    $newkeys = array('hck','scr','lcss','ftbl','bsktbl','stbl');

    $keyValueArray = array();   

    foreach($ids as $key=>$id)
    {
        $keyValueArray[$id] =$newkeys[$key];
    }


    $inputArr = array(1,3,7,8)  ;
    $outputArr = array();

    foreach($inputArr as $id)
    {
        $outputArr[$keyValueArray[$id]] = $id;
    }
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($outputArr);
    echo "</pre>";
```

I hope it will help you.

Comment: Three answers and three different interpretations of the question. :-) I actually think yours is the right one.